# Mysql Two parameters error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add data in mysql via input fields but my query not working properly.i have nine columns and also nine input fields.i know it;s not save way to insert data actually i am beginner.

my html input fields

```
<form method="post" >
<table>

<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Father Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="father" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Monthly Income</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="income" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Wasiyat Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wnumber" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Wasiyat Fund</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wasiyat" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tahrikaa Jadid Fund</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tahrikaa" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Waqfi Jadid Fund</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="waqfi" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Local Fund</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="local" /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jalsa Salana Fund</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="jalsa" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" /></td>
</tr>
   </table>
```

and here is my some php code for get form posts and also do query.
last time when i run code with var_dump value in this query falls. 
Php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{      
include 'db.php';

                $title=$_POST['name'] ;
                $author= $_POST['father'] ;                 
                $name=$_POST['income'] ;
                $copy=$_POST['wnumber'] ;
                $wasiyat=$_POST['wasiyat'];
                $tahrikaa_jadid=$_POST['tahrikaa'];
                $waqfi_jadid=$_POST['waqfi'];
                $local_fund=$_POST['local'];
                $jalsa=$_POST['jalsa'];

     $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `books`('name','father_name','monthly_income','wasiyat_number','wasiyat_fund','tahrikaa_jadid_fund','waqfi_jadid_fund','local_fund','jalsa_salana_fund') 
     VALUES    ('$title','$author','$name','$copy',$wasiyat,$tahrikaa_jadid,$waqfi_jadid,$local_fund,$jals a)"); 
                                    }
 ?>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: `$jals a` is not the same as `$jalsa`

Comment: Always check `mysql_error()` if `mysql_query()` returns **false**.

Comment: Where is your <form method="post" > ACTION ?

Comment: "I know it's not a safe way to insert data," but you're just going to do it anyway?

Comment: php code on same page so i don't need action.

Comment: and you don't need the quotes on  columns name on insert statment. ...(name, father_name, monthly_income, wasiyat_number, wasiyat_fund, tahrikaa_jadid_fund, waqfi_jadid_fund, local_fund, jalsa_salana_fund)...

Comment: use backtrics not ' '`

Comment: For one thing, change `$jals a` to `$jalsa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column names should either be enclosed in backticks `` or nothing at all. You're using single quotes which won't work.

```
INSERT INTO `books`('name'
                    ^    ^ wrong, should be `
```

Remove the space from `$jals a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it why your data not inserting.
1. `print_r($_POST);`

```
Check your post array have all fields value or not.
```

2.use mysql_error on your query it will help you know the root of problem as:

```
 $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `books`('name','father_name','monthly_income','wasiyat_number','wasiyat_fund','tahrikaa_jadid_fund','waqfi_jadid_fund','local_fund','jalsa_salana_fund') 
     VALUES    ('$title','$author','$name','$copy',$wasiyat,$tahrikaa_jadid,$waqfi_jadid,$local_fund,$jals a)") or die(mysql_error()); 

3. Check your table structure....
```

try to use mysqli_* function instead of mysql_* function